# html page missing the alignment in every iteration in Django Template

Tags: html, css, django

I have an HTML for cricket fixtures where I need to iterate it through the data in models. If I add a different div tag of the same content in the next line it gets aligned properly but when I'm generating the models data I see the alignment is changed to every iteration. It looks like the image [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Xhs.jpg)

**HTML code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fixture.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
    
    </header>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="container" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div id="shosh" class="ad-unit shosh-embed" style="height:0; width:980px; text-align:center;"></div>
            <div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>
                {% for fixture in fixtures %}   
            <div class="cb-bg-white cb-schdl cb-col cb-col-100">
                <h1 class='cb-schdl-hdr cb-font-24 line-ht30'>Cricket Schedule</h1>
                <div id="international-list" class="cb-bg-white">
                    <div class="cb-col-100 cb-col">
                        <div class="cb-lv-grn-strip text-bold">{{fixture.date}}</div>
                        <div class="cb-col-100 cb-col">
                            <div class="cb-col-33 cb-col cb-mtchs-dy text-bold">West Indies tour of England, 2020 (Postponed)</div>
                            <div class="cb-col-67 cb-col">
                                <div class="cb-ovr-flo cb-col-60 cb-col cb-mtchs-dy-vnu cb-adjst-lst"> <a href="/live-cricket-scores/23239/eng-vs-wi-1st-test-day-1-west-indies-tour-of-england-2020-postponed" title="ENG vs WI, 1st Test, Day 1 Live Cricket Score">England vs West Indies, 1st Test, Day 1</a>
                                    <div class="cb-font-12 text-gray cb-ovr-flo">Kennington Oval, London</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cb-col-40 cb-col cb-mtchs-dy-tm cb-adjst-lst"> <span class="schedule-date" timestamp="1591264800000" venue="+01:00" format="h:mm a"></span>
                                    <div class="cb-font-12 text-gray"> <span>10:00 AM</span> GMT /<span> 11:00 AM</span> LOCAL </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}                                              
                </div>    
            </div>
                
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    background: #E3E6E3;
    font-family: helvetica, "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
}

body,
.cb-comm-pg,
.cb-hm-mid {
    min-height: 1000px
}

.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.page {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.cb-col-8 {
    width: 8%;
}

.cb-col-10 {
    width: 10%;
}

.cb-col-14 {
    width: 14%;
}

.cb-col-16 {
    width: 16%;
}

.cb-col-20 {
    width: 20%;
}

.cb-col-25 {
    width: 25%;
}

.cb-col-27 {
    width: 27%;
}

.cb-col-33 {
    width: 33%;
}

.cb-col-40 {
    width: 40%;
}

.cb-col-46 {
    width: 46%;
}

.cb-col-47 {
    width: 47%;
}

.cb-col-50 {
    width: 50%;
}

.cb-col-60 {
    width: 60%;
}

.cb-col-66 {
    width: 66%;
}

.cb-col-67 {
    width: 67%;
}

.cb-col-73 {
    width: 73%;
}

.cb-col-75 {
    width: 75%;
}

.cb-col-84 {
    width: 84%;
}

.cb-col-80 {
    width: 80%;
}

.cb-col-90 {
    width: 90%;
}

.cb-col-100 {
    width: 100%;
}

.cb-col {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}

.cb-font-18 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
    outline: medium none;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.cb-nws-lft-col {
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.cb-nws-dtl-lft-col {
    padding: 10px 30px 0 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}

.cb-nws-lst-rt {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.cb-srs-lst-itm {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.cb-lst-itm-sm {
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
}

.cb-scrd-lft-col {
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

.cb-col-rt {
    padding: 10px;
}

.text-white {
    color: #fff;
}

.cb-scrd-hdr-rw,
.cb-nav-pill-1.active {
    background: #028062;
    color: #fff;
}

.cb-nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 48px;
    background: #009270;
}

.cb-hm-mnu-itm {
    padding: 16px 6px 11px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cb-hm-text {
    padding: 10px 18px 10px 20px;
}

.cb-hm-rght {
    padding: 15px;
}

.cb-subnav .cb-sub-navigation {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.cb-mat-mnu {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    width: 980px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.cb-mat-mnu-itm {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 140px;
}

.cb-mat-mnu-ttl {
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.cb-mat-mnu-wrp {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cb-ovr-flo {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cb-mat-mnu-all {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 60px;
}

.cb-nav-main {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e6e3;
    padding: 0 0 5px 20px;
}

.cb-nav-bar {
    padding-top: 10px;
    clear: both;
}

.cb-lst-itm,
.cb-bg-white {
    background: #fff;
}

.cb-nav-tab.active,
.cb-nav-tab-hm.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #028062;
}

.cb-nav-tab.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #028062;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.cb-nav-tab-hm.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #028062;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.cb-nav-tab {
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.cb-nav-tab-hm {
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.cb-nav-hdr {
    padding-top: 15px
}

.cb-nav-subhdr {
    padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
}

.cb-lv-scr-mtch-hdr {
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.disp-none {
    display: none;
}

.disp-blck {
    display: block;
}

.cb-font-24 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.line-ht30 {
    line-height: 30px;
}

.line-ht24 {
    line-height: 24px;
}

.cb-hm-scg-blk {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 90px;
}

.mrgn-btm-5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#scagTabContent .show {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

#scagTabContent .hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}

.cb-hm-lft {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.cb-hm-lft-hdr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 15px 0;
    color: #009270;
}

.cb-hm-mid {
    border-left: 5px solid #e3e6e3;
    border-right: 5px solid #e3e6e3;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.cb-mtch-blk {
    border-right: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.crd-cntxt {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.big-crd-main {
    border-top: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    padding: 15px 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    clear: both;
}

.big-crd-reltd-itm {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cb-nws-time {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.cb-nws-hdln-ancr {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.cb-hmscg-bwl-txt,
.cb-hmscg-bat-txt {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    height: 18px;
}

.cb-hmscg-bwl-txt {
    color: #666;
}

.sml-crd-main {
    padding: 15px 0 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.big-crd-hdln {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.big-crd-rltd-txt {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: #1866DB;
}

.cb-nws-intr {
    color: #666;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.cb-lv-scrs-well {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.cb-hm-mtch-crd-width {
    min-width: 300px;
}

.cb-mr-30 {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.cb-pretag {
    color: #B34A57;
}

.cb-schdl-hdr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 10px 10px;
}

.cb-lst-itm-lg {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.cb-left-pad {
    padding: 20px 10px 0;
}

.cb-nav-pill-1 {
    background: #CFE0DB;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

.cb-mtch-lst {
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.cb-nws-min-cntr {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #333;
    margin: 10px 0 15px;
}

.sml-crd-subtxt {
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
}
/*-------------------------Live Pages -----------------------*/

.cb-scrcrd-status {
    padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.cb-scrd-hdr-rw {
    padding: 8px 10px;
}

.cb-bg-gray {
    background: #ecebeb;
}

.cb-lv-grn-strip {
    background: #ecebeb;
}

.cb-min-hdr-rw,
.cb-scrd-sub-hdr {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
}

.cb-scrd-itms {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.cb-text-link {
    color: #1866DB;
}

.text-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text-normal {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cb-mat-fct-itm {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.cb-min-bat-rw {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.cb-nws-sub-txt,
.cb-nws-sub-txt,
.cb-font-12 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cb-font-16 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.cb-font-20 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.cb-min-inf {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cb-min-itm-rw {
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
}

.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.cb-key-st-lst {
    padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

.cb-min-prw-time {
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}

.cb-toss-sts {
    padding: 10px 0 30px;
}

.cb-min-rcnt {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    margin: 0 -10px 0;
}

.cb-key-lst-wrp {
    border: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.cb-min-tm {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.cb-min-stts {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.cb-mom-itm {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

.cb-lv-grn-strip {
    padding: 10px 10px 5px;
}

.cb-ovr-num {
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.cb-min-pad {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
/*Upcoming Series*/

.cb-mnth {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.cb-sch-lst-itm {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}
/*Matches By Day*/

.cb-mtchs-dy {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;
}

.cb-mtchs-dy-tm,
.cb-mtchs-dy-vnu {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
}
/*Schedule Teams*/

.cb-lv-upcom-strip {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #ecebeb;
}
/*Archives*/

.cb-srs-cat {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #028062;
}

.pad-left {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.cb-arcv-yr {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold
}

.cb-yr-tmline {
    padding: 2px 15px 15px 0;
}

.cb-sch-tms-widgt {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*Photos*/

.cb-thmb-dark {
    background: #333333;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: #CCC;
}

.cb-pht-main {
    padding: 20px 15px;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}

.cb-pht-block {
    padding: 9px;
    float: left;
    height: 280px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cb-gallery-pht-block {
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 16px;
}

.img-responsive {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.center-block {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.cb-schdl {
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.cb-caret-up,
.cb-caret-down {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.cb-caret-up {
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
}

.cb-caret-down {
    border-top: 4px solid;
}

.cb-hm-rt-itm {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px;
}

.cb-hmscg-tm-nm {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
}

.pull-right,
.cb-all-mtch-tab {
    float: right;
}

.cb-skin-ads-close {
    display: none;
}

.cb-nws-sub-txt {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.nws-dtl-hdln {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.cb-min-lv {
    min-height: 270px
}

.cb-min-comp {
    min-height: 150px;
}

.cb-ttl-vts {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.cb-poll-radio {
    width: 5%;
    margin: 4px 10px 0 0;
}

.cb-mini-tim {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.cb-com-ln {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.cb-comm-static {
    min-height: 31px;
    margin: 0 -10px 10px;
}

.cb-com-ovr-sum-ad {
    min-height: 31px;
}

.cb-comm-static-anchr {
    margin: 5px 10px;
    display: block;
}

.ad-unit-rendered {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.cb-mm-wrp {
    max-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cb-mm-wrp.down {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 0.75s ease;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.75s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cb-srs-hstry-dtl {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.cb-qck-lnk {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.cb-qck-hdr {
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}

.cb-qck-ancr {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.cb-lst-vid-rw {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 64px;
    border: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.cb-auth-img {
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.cb-expt-athr {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px
}

.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

.cb-exprt-athr-hdr {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: bodani;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 15px;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cb-exprt-athr-hdr-tag {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: bodani;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.cb-athr-wgt-wrp {
    border: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.cb-exprt-athr-hdr-img {
    background: url("/images/harsha-banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll;
    height: 80px;
}

.cb-overflow-hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*Videos*/

.cb-vid-sm-ply-api {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 34px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.cb-vid-sml-card-api {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 12px 0 11px;
}

.cb-cat-head-wrap {
    padding: 0 12px 0 11px;
}

.cb-cat-head-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.cb-more-btn {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #009270;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cb-cat-head-link {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.cb-pos-rel {
    position: relative;
}

.cb-videos-cat {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecebeb;
    padding: 10px 3px 15px 4px;
}

.cb-cat-head-text-wrap {
    float: left;
}

.cb-cat-head-count {
    margin: 0;
    color: #666;
}

h2.cb-cat-head-text {
    font-size: 18px
}

.cb-vid-sml-card-api-head {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    max-height: 55px;
    margin: 2px 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cb-cen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: .8;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: #222;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.cb-cen:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.padding-handling-errors {
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ecebeb;
}

.cb-col .cb-align-cen {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.cb-align-cen {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.cb-hot-cat {
    max-width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.cb-hot-cat-img {
    width: 72px;
}

.cb-vid-slider-arrs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

.cb-vid-slider-arr {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cb-vid-slider-arr-prev {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
}

.cb-vid-slider-arr-next {
    right: 0;
}

.videos-list-carousal {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 220px;
}

.videos-carousal-wrapper {
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.videos-carousal-item {
    min-width: 25%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.cb-vid-more {
    float: right;
    color: #2C3E9A;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.cb-vid-more:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.cat-vid-carousal {
    height: 135px !important;
}

.cat-vid-carousal .videos-carousal-item {
    min-width: auto;
}

.cat-vid-carousal .cb-vid-slider-arrs {
    top: 24px;
}

.cb-srs-sqd-box {
    min-height: 700px;
    background: #fff;
}

.cb-float-none {
    float: none;
}

.cb-margin-top-10 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.cb-schdl-nvtb {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cb-carousal-item-small {
    padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}

.cb-carousal-item-small:first-child {
    padding-left: 11px;
}

.cb-carousal-item-large {
    padding: 0 11px;
}

.cb-carousal-item-small .cb-vid-txt-wrp {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cb-hot-cat .cb-vid-txt-wrp {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 40px;
}

.cb-more-video {
    float: right;
    color: #2C3E9A;
}

.cb-more-video:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.home_video .cb-vid-slider-arrs {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
/*Rankings*/

.cb-ranking-nav.active {
    line-height: 21px
}

.cb-rank-plyr {
    padding-left: 15px
}

.text-left {
    text-align: left;
}

.cb-rank-tabs {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.cb-plyr-tbody {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.cb-padding-left0 {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.cb-rank-hdr {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.cb-bg-grey {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
/*Players*/

.cb-player-name-wrap {
    padding-top: 90px;
}

.cb-plyr-tbl {
    margin-top: 30px
}

.cb-font-40 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
/*Teams*/

.cb-cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cb-team-stats-btn {
    margin-top: 21px;
}

.cb-upper-text {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Does it fix the problem if the two `</div>`-tags directly after `{% endfor %}` are **before** the `endfor` ?

Comment: You saved a lot of time. I tried for hours and couldn't find it out .it looks good now. Thanks

Comment: In the future, you should consider posting a [mcve] of your code. Also, I think it is possible to combine CSS, HTML and JavaScript in a single snippet to get a runnable demonstration of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 closing `div`-tags which are **outside** your `for`-loop:

```
                {% endfor %}                                              
                </div>    
            </div>
```

If you put those 2 inside the loop it should work and render the html correctly:

```
                </div>    
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```